# Regression in PySpark. Which library to Use

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

What are the differences between "pyspark.mllib.regression" and "pyspark.ml.regression"

Which one should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the version of your spark. ml is suggested officially.

> As of Spark 2.0, the RDD-based APIs in the spark.mllib package have
>   entered maintenance mode. The primary Machine Learning API for Spark
>   is now the DataFrame-based API in the spark.ml package.

Hope this will help !